# SSRS function to change font colors

Tags: reporting-services

There is an error on line 17 of custom code: [BC30002] Type 'Value' is not defined.
Here is the function:
Public Function ChangeColor(input As Value) As Value
Return =IIf(input<0,"Red","Black")
End Function
Here is how I call it:
=Code.ChangeColor(Me.Value)

Comment: why use custom code for this? =IIF(Me.Value < 0,"Red","Black")

Comment: What's the use of a function? To stop refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:
Public Function ChangeColor(Byval input As integer) As String
 if input<0 then
  Return "Red"
 else
  return "Black"
 end if
End Function